# How do I compress inline css in the webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, optimization, native-web-component

I have an SPA using vanilla webcomponents, and I am struggling with compressing the inline css in the bundled js webpack output. Here's the module part of my webpack config:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.html$/i,
      loader: "html-loader",
      exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.html")
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/i,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'css-loader'
    }
  ],
}
```

In my components I import css like this:

```
import css from "./entityPage.css";
```

In my component css e.g. *./entityPage.css* I refer to the "outer css" like this

```
@import "../../style.css";
```

Here is an extract of the inline css in the webpack bundle output:

```
c.push([e.id,"#h2puIrptVrtsTvV8FGBM{\r\n    width: 40%;\r\n    min-width: 614px; /*48 x the character w with font-size 1rem ;) */\r\n    border: solid 1px black;\r\n\r\n}\r\n\r\n#eKOgREy00yPONhrgY8Zg{\r\n    font-weight: bold;\r\n
```

As seen whitespace, lineshifts and even comments are preserved.

I have tried multiple combinations of mini-css-extract-plugin, css-minimizer-webpack-plugin, postcss-loader without luck, so a working example of the css rule setup in webpack config would be really appreciated. (with eventual plugins / optimization setup if appropriate)

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[postcss / postcss-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-loader) was the way to go in my context.

The webpack.config module rule for my css files looks like this:

```
    {
      test: /\.css$/i,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader'
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out CSSO (https://github.com/css/csso). You can use this with Webpack.  There some documentation there on how to set it up with WebPack.

An alternative way is to let the IDE compile this for you automatically.

What I do is to code in SCSS - which will automatically compile to CSS when I change the file. This is set up in PHPStorm File Watchers. PHPStorm detects external changes in CSS (as it was generated from SCSS) and it applies Autoprefixer and CSSO optimizer to minimize the CSS.

I also made my own CLI tool to automatically compile that CSS to native JavaScript module for better performance and quicker compiling - so I don't need Webpack to do this. You can get my CLI tool here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csshtml-module

This should also work well with Webpack as the end result is native JS/TS. And you get the benefit of SCSS compiling and optimization outside of your JS library as well.

Similar approach can be done in VSCode, and probably other IDE's as well.

Comment: This does not work in my context.